# Unable to set value attribute for placeholder if value is empty using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a sample HTML code with script tag using jquery:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var email_def= "Enter email address";
        $('input[type="email"]').attr('value', email_def).focus(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == email_def) {
                $(this).attr('value', '');
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val == '') {
                $(this).attr('value', email_def);
                alert(val);
                alert(email_def);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Email: <input type="email"> <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click in the input box. Placeholder value is cleared. Click outside, placeholder value is now reset back.
2. Click in the input box. Type some text. Delete the text. Click outside. The placeholder value is not reset back.The alert are triggered. Even the email_def is being shown in alert. Now, the attribute value is not being reset to value of email_def.
   My question is why is the line `$(this).attr('value', email_def);` not being invoked inside the blur function.

Edit: Thanks for the answers. Both, the placeholder of html5 and also replacing with the `$(this).val();` line seems to be working correctly

Comment: Why not just use input placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use HTML5 Placeholder attribute**

> A hint to the user of what can be entered in the control . The
>   placeholder text must not contain carriage returns or line-feeds. This
>   attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text,
>   search, tel, url or email; otherwise it is ignored.

http://jsfiddle.net/xj7v8gd7/

```
<form action="<some action>">
  <input type="email" id="emailForm" size="30" placeholder="Enter email address"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO if you are only dealing with modern browsers. IE9 and below do not support placeholders. You could always add a polyfill for this feature though. Here are the browsers that support it: [http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `$(this).attr('value', email_def);`, consider `$(this).val(email_def);`. It will behave as you've specified.

Rafael is correct to suggest using HTML's `placeholder` instead, unless you have some specific need regarding Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Rafael is correct. However, if you need it to work in browsers old enough that they don't support the placeholder attribute, just switch your value attribute setters to use the overload on val() instead. So:

```
$(this).val('Enter the email address') //for example
```

See that demonstrated below (it looked like only the one in the blur method was actually a problem.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var email_def = "Enter email address...";
      $('input[type="email"]').attr('value', email_def).focus(function() {
        //alert('focus');
        if ($(this).val() === email_def) {
          $(this).val('');
        }
      }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
          $(this).val(email_def);
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Email:
  <input type="email" id="emailForm" size="30" />
  <input type="submit" id="submitForm" />
</form>
```